# Pokémon on Windows Phone

Tags: pokemon-go, windows-phone

Is there any way to play Pokémon Go on Windows 10 phone? I've found on ther internet that Microsoft looks a way to play it on Win 10. But I'll know if there is a way to play it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the time of writing, there is no way to load Pokemon GO on a Windows Phone legitimately.

Niantic (for reasons which we do not understand) has decided to not release a version of the game for this platform of device. Ingress was also never ported over to Windows Phone, due to concerns about spoofing.

---

Microsoft initially planned a project known as Project Astoria, which would allow for non-native Android apps to run on any Universal Windows platform (Windows Phone and Windows 10). However, it has been delayed many times and is unlikely to ever see the light of day.

You could, of course, attempt to find an Android emulator and sideload the APK, but I have been unable to find any reputable ones, and using them runs the risk of getting your account banned for cheating.

Comment: Being able to at least try to play it with the emulator is probably worth the risk, because if he gets banned he can just create a new account when / if he gets a new phone anyways.

Comment: I'm unsure why you put "for reasons which we do not understand".  The lack of a version for Windows Phone is very understandable; even though they may not have made an official statement, I can't see them bothering to put the development effort and resources into a platform which will net them only a small fraction of players on Android and iPhone.

Comment: @AdamMiller It's Unity, meaning they press a few buttons and it magically appears.